# facebook : Unable to download og:image?

Tags: facebook, image

at the debug page :

we input page : http://www.hkofferhouse.com/items/last-update/20121020/list.htm
work fine , and we can get picture thumbnail and we can choose thumbnail .

but if input page : http://www.hkofferhouse.com/items/last-update/20121019/list.htm
Unable to download og:image . cannot get picture thumbnail .

this 2 page about  setting is same . but why many page can get thumbnail . and many page cannot get thumbnail  ?

please help . many thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Try running the links via the Debugger. 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hkofferhouse.com%2Fitems%2Flast-update%2F20121019%2Flist.htm

It seems like the og:image url is incorrectly configured, there were 2 .jpg extensions.

```
meta property="og:image" content="http://www.hkofferhouse.com/GAME/PS3/ps390653/ps390653p.jpg.jpg"
```